# Migrating and Ingres Data Base to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, migrate, ingres, dbmigrate

I have a cline that is looking to convert an Ingres Database into SQL Server 2008. WE can easily convert the tables but there are a large number of views and procedures that are complex. Does anyone know of a method or tool that can convert these procedures etc without a manual process of doing so.

Thanks

Lee Tedstone.

Answer (score 0):

Lee, I am quite sure there is no such migration tool available at the moment (one that can translate Ingres stored procedures to adequate SQL server ones). Such tool is not trivial to do - one needs to code a language-to-language translator in order to accomplish this.

However, there is a nice (Ingres) project called "Idiom" - http://community.ingres.com/wiki/Idiom - which can give you some clue how to write such translator.

Idiom is used in the Ingres Migration ToolSet project -  http://community.ingres.com/wiki/IngresMigrationToolSet - which successfully translates Oracle and MySQL procedures to Ingres.